# Is it possible to use electron.js along with vue 3 and vite, having hot reload in electron?

Tags: electron, vuejs3

My main.js loads HTML through this piece of code:

```
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/index.html'))
```

And everytime I change something, I have to stop and run "vite build && electron ."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Quasar offers hot-reloads of both renderer and main process; that is the HMR they refer to at https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-electron-apps/build-commands#developing

This plugin says it offers hot-reloads (I haven't personally used it):
https://electron-vite.github.io/guide/why-electron-vite.html

And this tutorial shows doing it by using @vitejs/plugin-vue:
https://dev.to/lucacicada/how-to-set-up-vite-and-electron-from-scratch-with-any-frontend-framework-40mb   (which they've turned into their own plugin: https://github.com/armoniacore/armonia-vite )

I wasn't able to find an example that doesn't use plugins. The third example seems the lowest level if you are keen to learn how it works.